# Download Other APP in iOS App

Tags: ios

In my application there is a button to download other app from app store.

When user click on this button , my app open app store for particular app.

If user click on download and download application , how can my app get to know that user has successfully downloaded a particular application.

Comment: Does the newly downloaded app support its own custom URL scheme? If so, check for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can poll for the successful installation, but you can't be notified of it.

Three steps:

- all of your applications must register custom URL handlers as in myapp1:, myapp2:, myapp3, ...
- In your plist, add an entry for LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and list all of your other apps as in myapp2:, myapp3:, etc.
- poll for the availability of the URL using:
  `if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp2:"]])`

Comment: Why would you poll? Just check when the app returns to the foreground.

Comment: Thinking about the experience. I jump out to App Store, download myapp2, then return to original app. No way to know whether new app installation would have completed. Would to figure out a rule for when to give up checking in case the user did not download myapp2.